# Can't boot from new SSD on my laptop

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I have a Samsung NP770Z7E laptop that came with Windows 8 pre-installed.

Yesterday, I installed a SSD in place of the HDD, and put the HDD in place of the optical bay, that I don't really use.

Now, I went to the F4 Recovery and copied the factory image to SSD. But I can't boot from it, it always boots to the HDD Windows.

I also tried booting from a USB Pen with Windows 8.1 to try to clean install in on the SSD, but I can't boot from it either. On the drive selection menu, when I start the pc, the only option that appears is "Windows Boot Manager".

I'm sure the USB pen is bootable as I used Rufus and made sure to select the "GPT partition scheme for UEFI computer" option, and made sure it was FAT32.

I also disabled Fast Bios, Secure Boot and set OS Mode Selection as "UEFI & CSM OS".

I'm not sure what else to do... Is there a simple option to tell the boot manager to boot from the ssd?

Comment: Try removing the HDD and booting from SSD or USB, then what happens?

Comment: Yes, that would be a last resort option, since it was a pain to open this laptop and I would rather not do it again.

Comment: But that is how the trouble shooting process works.  You have to get back to a known good configuration and work from there changing, then "test and measure".  You can run the laptop with it in pieces usually, as in you usually do not have to screw everything back together to get it to work to make the process of adding and removing go faster as you troubleshoot.

Comment: Yeah, managed to do it kind of that way. Didn't boot from anywhere though, used Samsung Recovery that I had on the cloned SSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to reopen the laptop and take out the HDD and clone it again to the SSD.

With only the SSD inside, it managed to install Windows and boot from it. Then I just placed the HDD inside and all is well now.

Answer (score 1):

Open the BIOS and change the boot order, to SSD first.

Comment: The only thing that appears on boot order is Windows Boot Manager. It doesn't appear the SSD nor an USB drive... And both appear when I'm on Windows.

Comment: Try a linux CD to check if the drive is visible to systems

Comment: The SSD drive is visible in Windows, it just isn't visible available to boot drom at boot time. I don't have an optical drive right now, took it off to put the SSD. I just don't understand why I can't boot from my usb pen with Windows 8 x64 either, formatted to fat32 and gpt.

Comment: Your BIOS may not work with your SSD. Try updating the BIOS.